# Headers in static middleware

Tags: node.js, connect, express

How can I set headers in Static middleware response? I need to define utf-8 as charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a direct override, that doesn't look like an option. Connect's [documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) shows that it determines the charset based on the mime-type via the [`mime`](https://github.com/bentomas/node-mime) module. The `mime` module appears to let you customize it's definitions, so I'd check that out first.